# PostgreSQL : password authentication failed for user "sean"

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database, postgresql

So I've looked around all over the place for an answer for this but I cannot find one anywhere.

so I'm trying to setup a PostgreSQL database with nodeJS and I've installed pgadmin3 etc.

here is my code

```
const express = require("express");
const pg = require("pg");

const connect = "postgres://sean:sean@localhost/karls"

var pool = new pg.Pool(connect);

router.route("/").get((req, res) => {
    pool.connect(function(err, client, done){
        if(err) return console.error("the error ocurred on: " + err);
        client.query("SELECT * FROM Recipe", function(err, result) {
            if(err) console.error(error);
            console.log(results)
            done();
        })
    })
});
```

on my pgadmin3 I have a login role named sean as a super user so I don't know why it's not connecting I have the password correct but it keeps spitting out this error:

> error: password authentication failed for user "sean";

I've been trying to fix this for ages if you need any more information let me know and ill update the question

I've solved this problem :)

Comment: I think it would be useful to see your pg_ident.conf and pg_hba.conf files (on mobile, so may have got the filenames a bit wrong!)

Comment: ive solved the problem but thanks for the reply anyways :)